# Retrieving specific number of rows in group by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'userId': [10,20,10,20,10,20,60,90,60,90,60,90,30,40,30,40,30,40,50,60,50,60,50,60],
                   'movieId': [500,500,800,800,700,700,1100,1100,1900,1900,2000,2000,1600,1600,1901,1901,3000,3000,3025,3025,4000,4000,500,500],  
                   'ratings': [3.5,4.5,2.0,5.0,4.0,1.5,3.5,4.5,3.5,4.5,2.0,5.0,4.0,1.5,3.5,4.5,3.5,4.5,2.0,5.0,4.0,1.5,3.5,4.5]})
```

```
df
    userId  movieId  ratings
0       10      500      3.5
1       20      500      4.5
2       10      800      2.0
3       20      800      5.0
4       10      700      4.0
5       20      700      1.5
6       60     1100      3.5
7       90     1100      4.5
8       60     1900      3.5
9       90     1900      4.5
10      60     2000      2.0
11      90     2000      5.0
12      30     1600      4.0
13      40     1600      1.5
14      30     1901      3.5
15      40     1901      4.5
16      30     3000      3.5
17      40     3000      4.5
18      50     3025      2.0
19      60     3025      5.0
20      50     4000      4.0
21      60     4000      1.5
22      50      500      3.5
23      60      500      4.5
```

1. In this dataframe two users have common movies between them.
2. The `userId` can be taken as pairs for understanding purpose `e.g.[(10,20),(60,90),(30,40),(50,60)]`.
3. As all of these pairs have common movies between them. After every 6 entries new pair entries are starting.
4. Moreover, one user can appear in multiple pairing as in this dataframe e.g.`userId = 60` is twice.
5. I want to pick `e.g. first 4` entries from each pair.

```
**Expected Outcome**

    userId  movieId  ratings
0       10      500      3.5
1       20      500      4.5
2       10      800      2.0
3       20      800      5.0

6       60     1100      3.5
7       90     1100      4.5
8       60     1900      3.5
9       90     1900      4.5

12      30     1600      4.0
13      40     1600      1.5
14      30     1901      3.5
15      40     1901      4.5

18      50     3025      2.0
19      60     3025      5.0
20      50     4000      4.0
21      60     4000      1.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert pairs to tuples per groups with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and then call [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
s = df['movieId'].map(df.groupby('movieId')['userId'].apply(tuple))

df = df.groupby(s).head(6)
print (df)
    userId  movieId  ratings
0       10      500      3.5
1       20      500      4.5
2       10      800      2.0
3       20      800      5.0
4       10      700      4.0
5       20      700      1.5
8       30     1900      3.5
9       40     1900      4.5
10      30     2000      2.0
11      40     2000      5.0
12      30     1600      4.0
13      40     1600      1.5
16      50     3000      3.5
17      60     3000      4.5
18      50     3025      2.0
19      60     3025      5.0
20      50     4000      4.0
21      60     4000      1.5
```

EDIT:

If is necessary filtering by consecutive `movieID`:

```
tmp = df['movieId'].ne(df['movieId'].shift()).cumsum()
s = tmp.map(df.groupby(tmp)['userId'].apply(tuple))
df = df.groupby(s).head(4)
print (df)
    userId  movieId  ratings
0       10      500      3.5
1       20      500      4.5
2       10      800      2.0
3       20      800      5.0
6       60     1100      3.5
7       90     1100      4.5
8       60     1900      3.5
9       90     1900      4.5
12      30     1600      4.0
13      40     1600      1.5
14      30     1901      3.5
15      40     1901      4.5
18      50     3025      2.0
19      60     3025      5.0
20      50     4000      4.0
21      60     4000      1.5
```

EDIT:

> Is it better to exclude every 2 rows after picking first 4? It will do the job. Any suggestions? I mean it will pick 4 then remove next 2 and pick another 4 and remove next 2 and so on.

You can use modulo of `6` with index values, then filter by condition and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#for default RangeIndex
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df[df.index % 6 < 4]
print (df)
    userId  movieId  ratings
0       10      500      3.5
1       20      500      4.5
2       10      800      2.0
3       20      800      5.0
6       60     1100      3.5
7       90     1100      4.5
8       60     1900      3.5
9       90     1900      4.5
12      30     1600      4.0
13      40     1600      1.5
14      30     1901      3.5
15      40     1901      4.5
18      50     3025      2.0
19      60     3025      5.0
20      50     4000      4.0
21      60     4000      1.5
```

Comment: it's not working in my original dataframe. I have pairing of users which can be repetitive. ` e.g. [(10,20), (20,40), (40,60), (10,50)]`. Would your code work even in this scenario?

Comment: i can't filter like this as you mentioned above.

Comment: in my scenario different users can watch same movie. For example i have movies with users `(10,20),(10,30),(40,30)`. So each user can be paired with an other user but same users pair is not in the dataframe. for example, `(10,20),(20,10)`.

Comment: Is it better to exclude every 2 rows after picking first 4? It will do the job. Any suggestions? I mean it will pick 4 then remove next 2 and pick another 4 and remove next 2 and so on.